# How to transfer (merge) account from former company, (Google Apps)

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I appear to have created an account using my former employer's Google Apps email; I can no longer access that email account but I can still log in to *SO* using a linked Yahoo account.  I would like to merge that account (and my reputation, etc.) with my personal account, linked to my gmail and facebook accounts.

How can I move/merge two accounts, e.g.

tharrison@myoldcompany.com (google apps email)
tharrison@yahoo.com (via OpenID)

with

tharrison@gmail.com (not my real gmail account, via OpenID)
tharrison Facebook account

Thanks!

Tom

Comment: Have you tried adding the Gmail account as an alternate login for your other account? They should automatically merge if they have the same login.

Comment: Thanks -- I tried, but now it seems I cannot log in using my Google Apps credentials any more.  I tried using a Yahoo account, and it seems to know about both this account (my personal one) and the my old company account ... but not sure how to proceed.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, I'll go ahead and merge them manually then.